# I want to display identity column populated in textbox that is generated by database using ADO.NET / ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

Model class `Department`:

```
[Table("Department")]
public class Department
{
    [Display(Name ="Sno")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Department_Id")]
    public String Dno { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Department_Name")]
    public String Dname { get; set; }
}
```

Repository class

```
public List<Department> GetDepartmentList()
{
        connection();
        List<Department> list = new List<Department>();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SpDepartmentList", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        con.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            list.Add(
                new Department
                {
                    id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"]),
                    Dno = Convert.ToString(dr["Dno"]),
                    Dname = Convert.ToString(dr["Dname"]),
                    //DnoList = Convert.To(dr["DnoList"])
                });
        }

        return list;
}
```

Submitting data using ADO.NET in the `Repository` class:

```
public bool AddDepartment(Department obj)
{
        connection();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddDepartments", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dname", obj.Dname);

        con.Open();
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        if (i >= 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddDepartment()
{
    // Here I want get Dno id displayed that is generated by 
    // database with that id I have to submit data to data table
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddDepartment(Department Dep)
{
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                DepartmentRep Repo = new DepartmentRep();

                if (Repo.AddDepartment(Dep))
                {
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    ViewBag.Message = "Details added successfully";
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Department] 
(
    [id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Dno] AS (CONCAT('Dno_', [id])),
    [Dname] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Dno] ASC)
);
```

I have populate `Dno` that is an identity automatically generated by database. With that id I have to submit data to database in to the table using ADO.NET.

Please can anyone help me?

I am new to this website if I did any mistake please excuse me.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow ,Where do you want to show `Dno` column? What did you try and what error occurred? If you do not provide us with this information, we do not know how to help you , please read this before posting a new question [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for response. I want submit data to data table with 'Dno'. Dno  is generated by database . Dno is displayed on browser with not editable. Dno and user entering Dname submit to Department Table .

Comment: What's the code of `spAddDepartments`?

Comment: 'CREATE procedure spAddDepartments 
  @Dname nvarchar(50)=null
As
Begin
  Insert into Department(Dname)
  Values (@Dname)
End'

Comment: Just I want to display "Dno" in textbox that is not editable

Comment: Return `Dno` from the sproc.

Answer (score -1):

To display the `Dno` (identity column) generated by the database when adding a new `Department`, you can follow these steps:

1. Modify your `AddDepartment` action method to fetch the generated `Dno` after inserting the data into the database using ADO.NET.
2. Pass the generated `Dno` to your view, so it can be displayed to the user.

Here's how you can modify your code:

Controller (Add the `OUTPUT` clause to the SQL query):

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddDepartment(Department Dep)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DepartmentRep Repo = new DepartmentRep();

            int generatedDno = Repo.AddDepartment(Dep); // Get the generated Dno

            if (generatedDno > 0)
            {
                ModelState.Clear();
                ViewBag.Message = "Details added successfully";
                ViewBag.GeneratedDno = generatedDno; // Pass the generated Dno to the view
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Repository (Return the generated Dno):

```cs
public int AddDepartment(Department obj)
{
    connection();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAddDepartments", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dname", obj.Dname);

    SqlParameter outputParam = new SqlParameter("@GeneratedDno", SqlDbType.Int)
    {
        Direction = ParameterDirection.Output // Define an OUTPUT parameter to get the generated Dno
    };
    cmd.Parameters.Add(outputParam);

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    if (outputParam.Value != DBNull.Value)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(outputParam.Value); // Return the generated Dno
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

View (Display the generated Dno):

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddDepartment";
}

<h2>Add Department</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Department</h4>
        <hr />

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @if (ViewBag.GeneratedDno > 0)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Generated Dno:</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @ViewBag.GeneratedDno
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

In this modified code:

- The `AddDepartment` method in your repository now returns the generated `Dno` as an `int`. It also defines an `OUTPUT` parameter in the SQL command to retrieve the generated `Dno`.
- The controller's `AddDepartment` action method now fetches the generated `Dno` from the repository and passes it to the view using `ViewBag`.
- The view checks if `ViewBag.GeneratedDno` is greater than 0 (indicating a valid generated `Dno`) and displays it to the user if available.